# How to change this React(Redux) Component so it works by itself

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I learn React Redux and have some issues.

In the code below I do `mapStateToProps` to listen for changes and I use the `mapDispatchToProps` to send a notification. When there is a change in the `Store` I send a Notification. In order for this to work I have to put this `Helper` in the App.jsx `render()` method even do this `Helper` Component code below does not add anything to the App.jsx. I learn React and wonder how I can change this Notefication.js so it listen for `mapStateToProps` and can do `mapDispatchToProps` without adding it to App.jsx `render()`.

It just feels so unnecessary to have to add this Component to the App.jsx render only to get the `mapStateToProps` `mapDispatchToProps` working?

Notefication.js

```
   import { connect } from "react-redux";
import 'react-redux-notify/dist/ReactReduxNotify.css';
import { createNotification, NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SUCCESS } from 'react-redux-notify';
import { Notify } from 'react-redux-notify';
import React, { Component } from "react";

const mySuccessNotification = {
  message: 'You have been logged in!',
  type: NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SUCCESS,
  duration: 0,
  canDismiss: true,
  icon: <i className="fa fa-check" />
}

class Helper extends Component {

  senNotification() {
    const { createNotification } = this.props;
    createNotification(mySuccessNotification);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Notify />
        {this.senNotification()}
  </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  createNotification: (config) => {
    dispatch(createNotification(config))
  },
})

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return { badword: state.rootReducer.badword };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Helper)
```

App.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import List from "./List.jsx";
import Form from "./Form.jsx";
import Helper from "../components/Notification";
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        const { addToast } = this.props.actions;
        addToast({ text: "Hello, World!" });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <main>
                <div className="row mt-5">
                    <div className="col-md-4 offset-md-1">
                        <h2>Articles</h2>
                        <List />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-md-4 offset-md-1">
                        <h2>Add a new article</h2>
                        <Form />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <Helper/>
            </main>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React only renders new, if the component values changes. So if the reducer is connected and you load some values which changes, the component renders and the function will be triggered.

I would not trigger the function `this.senNotification` in the render function I would prefer to use `componentDidUpdate` to trigger the function.

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import 'react-redux-notify/dist/ReactReduxNotify.css';
import { createNotification, NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SUCCESS } from 'react-redux-notify';
import { Notify } from 'react-redux-notify';
import React, { Component } from "react";

const mySuccessNotification = {
  message: 'You have been logged in!',
  type: NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SUCCESS,
  duration: 0,
  canDismiss: true,
  icon: <i className="fa fa-check" />
}

class Helper extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
    const { createNotification, badword } = this.props

    if(prevProps.badword !== badword) {
       this.senNotification()
    }

  }

  senNotification() {
    const { createNotification } = this.props;
    createNotification(mySuccessNotification);
  }
  render() {
    return <Notify />
  }

....
}
```